# ng2-handsontable Access to ng component properties from inside renderer

Tags: typescript, handsontable

Is there any way to access to the properties defined in the host component from inside of a renderer function ? I tried to use the keyword "this" but it always is undefined.

```
import * as Handsontable from 'handsontable';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: "my-component",
  templateUrl: "my-component.component.html"
})
export class MyComponentComponent
  {

  public  newColumns: any[] = [{
          data: 'A',
          renderer: this.styleRenderer
        }];

 public data :any[] = [{A:'1'}]
  constructor(
  ) {
  }

  public styleRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {

    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log('is this null ?:',this);  //<-  "this" is always undefined in the given context

  }


}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you are not initializing the array `cellStyles:array<any> = new array<any>();` should fix this issue

Comment: thank you Aravind, but that is not the problem, I just edited the question and added more information.

Comment: when you are updating the property? can I see the complete code??

Comment: thank you Aravind,  the problem is not the value that cellStyles has, it is just an example I'm using to show that the key word THIS , that we use to refer to the host component and to get access to the properties is undefined, so, we can't get access to it's properties. It only happens inside of the styleRender function context.

Comment: where is this function written in a separate file? can you post the full code?

Comment: it is inside the ng component , I just updated and simplified the source code

Comment: try this in constructor.I think the problem is the line before console.log which causeing error and that is why this is getting undefined

Comment: {this} works everywhere but inside the renderer function.

Answer (score 0):

Try below based on [what I found here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ykm8c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.ts)

```
const $component = this;

public newColumns: any[] = [{
  data: 'A',
  renderer: (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) => {    
    console.log('is this null ?:', $component);  //<-  Try using $component from above instead of this
  }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

It works by using an arrow function:

```
    styleRenderer = (hotTable: any, td: HTMLElement, row: any, col: any,
        prop: any, value: string, cellProperties: any) => {
        // 'this' component can be referenced from here
    }
```